# How do I get the expected bounds of an image to be drawn with transforms to canvas via drawImage()?

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage

I'm trying to draw an image using drawImage(), but with a matrix transform applied to it, like rotation or skew. Is there some way to get the expected bounds of this transformed image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a rectangle's x,y,width,height,rAngle,skewX,skewY:

**The bounding box of a rotated rectangle:**

```
// rAngle is in radians
var absCos=Math.abs(Math.cos(rAngle));
var absSin=Math.abs(Math.sin(rAngle));
var centerX=x+width/2*Math.cos(rAngle)-height/2*Math.sin(rAngle);
var centerY=y+width/2*Math.sin(rAngle)+height/2*Math.cos(rAngle); 
var newWidth=width*absCos+height*absSin;
var newHeight=width*absSin+height*absCos;
```

**The bounding box of a skewed rectangle:**

```
// skewX & skewY are in the range 0.00 to 1.00
var left = x * (1+skewX);
var top = y * (1+skewY);
var newWidth = width * (1+skewX);
var newHeight = height * (1+skewY);
```